# what is output.crossOriginLoading for in webpack's config?

Tags: webpack

**output.crossOriginLoading**, if I set it to **true** in the configuration, then what will be different in the compiled bundle? Is it that some code for **JSONP** will be added? And you can use another computer to debug the web by connecting to the **webpack-dev-server**?

Answer (score 5):

Webpack chunks are included in a running application by injecting on the fly the page with `<script>` tags.

Some HTML elements like `<script>` tags provide support for [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) to cover those scenarios where a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing configuration is needed. *(eg linked files loaded from a different domain)*.

Webpack's [`output.crossOriginLoading`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-crossoriginloading) setting is meant to configure the `crossorigin` attribute of such generated `<script>` elements.